# Git mirror & creating pipelines

Tags: git, gitlab, bitbucket

I have already one repository in BitBucket.

Same repo I have in Gitlab.

I want to mirror that repo in GitLab & need to create Pipelines.

So once code push to BitBucket repo it automatically goes to Gitlab.

Does any one have steps for that? to folllow

Answer (score 1):

Git mirroring is available on Gitlab, see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html

Keep in mind that you will need to have the pipelines definition for Bitbucket and for Gitlab, if you want to run them on both.